# Проблемы с библиотекой mocha в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, type-error, mocha

При создании пробного/шаблонного авто-теста столкнулся с проблемой которую не могу понять как решить (сами библиотеки установлены)
Вот мой код:

```
const { describe, before, after, beforeEach, afterEach, it } = require('mocha');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('Test Suite', () => {
  let browser;
  let page;

  before(async () => {
    // Запустить браузер перед началом всех тестов
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  });

  after(async () => {
    // Закрыть браузер после выполнения всех тестов
    await browser.close();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // Создать новую страницу перед каждым тестом
    page = await browser.newPage();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    // Закрыть страницу после каждого теста
    await page.close();
  });

  it('should display "Google" in the title', async () => {
    // Перейти на сайт Google
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');

    // Проверить, что заголовок страницы содержит "Google"
    const title = await page.title();
    expect(title).to.include('Google');
  });
});
```

А ошибка которую мне выдаёт выглядит так:

```
$ node test4.js
C:\cygwin64\home\Mio\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:111
  return (currentContext.describe || currentContext.suite).apply(this, args);
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'describe')
    at exports.describe (C:\cygwin64\home\Mio\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:111:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\cygwin64\home\Mio\test4.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1246:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1300:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v19.5.0
```

При запуске через `mocha test4.js` появляется другая ошибка:

```
$ mocha test4.js

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'describe')
    at exports.describe (C:\cygwin64\home\Mio\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:111:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\cygwin64\home\Mio\test4.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1246:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1300:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:168:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
```

Comment: Тест выглядит правильным. Можете поделиться командой запуска, конфигом и его расположением? Предполагаю, что есть проблемы именно с запуском тестов

Comment: команда запуска ```node test4.js``` а расположено всё ```C:\cygwin64\home\Mio```

Comment: При написании этой же программы, но без ```mocha``` всё работает как часы, но мне очень интересно в чём же тут проблема

Comment: В общем-то, запускать нужно через `mocha test4.js`. Если по-простому - особенности реализации библиотеки. Ошибка говорит, что `currentContext` является `undefined`, а при запуске через команду `mocha` этот контекст появляется. Подробнее не могу объяснить, раннее не с либой работал

Comment: попробуйте удалить папку node_modules и затем выполните команду npm install, чтобы установить все зависимости заново

Comment: и попробуйте заменить `const { describe, before, after, beforeEach, afterEach, it } = require('mocha');` на `const Mocha = require('mocha');
const { describe, before, after, beforeEach, afterEach, it } = Mocha;`

Comment: @MioMelliot я думал вопрос уже решен после ответа SiRanWeb разве нет? Что-то не выходит? Опишите реальное состояние проблемы на текущий момент. Правильный вариант запуска теста согласно документации через скрипт в `package.json` :  `"test": "mocha"`,  файлы тестов должны быть в папке "test"  в корне проекта

Comment: на всякий случай документация [на русском](https://mochajs-org.translate.goog/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=wapp), причина Вашей ошибки в том что при запуске разных файлов список зависимостей разный и в итоге не подтягиваются нужные глобальные переменные

Comment: нет ни один из предложенных вариантов не подходит ошибка не меняется сколько бы я не переустанавливал или менял способ импортирования... походу какие-то траблы с фалами. Попробовал даже перекинуть проект в другую папку и заново установить все библиотеки локально но исход тот же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно заменить
`const { describe, before, after, beforeEach, afterEach, it } = require('mocha');`

на

```
const Mocha = require('mocha'); 
const { describe, before, after, beforeEach, afterEach, it } = Mocha;
```

Comment: Странное поведение библиотеки...

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение всё было проще чем я думал, но я не уверен, что понимаю как это работает...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('Test Suite', () => {
  let browser;
  let page;

  before(async function () {
    // Запустить браузер перед началом всех тестов
    this.timeout(5000);
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  });

  after(async function () {
    // Закрыть браузер после выполнения всех тестов
    await browser.close();
  });

  beforeEach(async function () {
    // Создать новую страницу перед каждым тестом
    page = await browser.newPage();
  });

  afterEach(async function () {
    // Закрыть страницу после каждого теста
    if (page) {
      await page.close();
    }
  });

  it('should display "Google" in the title', async function () {
    // Перейти на сайт Google
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');

    // Проверить, что заголовок страницы содержит "Google"
    const title = await page.title();
    expect(title).to.include('Google');
  });
});
```

Оказалось нужно было просто убрать прямое импортирование библиотеки `Mocha`

```
const Mocha = require('mocha');
const { describe, before, after, beforeEach, afterEach, it } = Mocha;
```

я удалил эту часть кода и всё заработало как-то

Comment: как я и сказал))

Comment: @SeniorPomidor как тебе передать вознаграждение? Просто комментарии нельзя отметить как ответ...